# Trying to rename a file in Amazon S3. Getting specified key does not exist error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#move_to-instance_method)

This is how I'm trying to rename my file:

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new("bucket-key")
object = S3.bucket.object("key-to-object")
object.move_to(bucket: "bucket-key", key: "key-to-destination")
```

I've also tried changing the target to a string and an object but both don't work :(

I've also tried just using the `copy_to` and `delete` commands but the `copy_to` is erroring just the same.

Comment: Are you sure the bucket exists and that there are not typos in your bucket name, or object name? Are you including the bucket name in the `key` parameter to `move_to`? Note that it needs the full object key including bucket name.

Comment: if you are using a string for the target the syntax is object.move_to("bucket-key/key-to-destination").  Are you certain that the original object exists?

Comment: Ah yeah I was dumb and had a bug somewhere else in the code so my original object never existed. Just to help anybody else debugging I ran `object.content_length` to see if the original object existed. Thanks @dbugger. 

@ErmiyaEskandary I fixed it but the key parameter doesn't include the bucket name. You might be referring to when you reference the target with a string?